# Getting Unity 2D Perspective Camera + World Space Canvas Image sorting to work

Tags: unity-game-engine

These are my current settings and let me know if you all need more information to help me solve this issue.

Camera : Perspective

Canvas Render Mode : World Space

In the picture below the focus here is when the user wants to select a ship of their choice they click where "Select V" is and you see "Fighter *ship image*, but the problem here is that not only is the "Green Circle" in the way but the dropdown itself it just not big enough.

[image]

In this second picture below you can see the scaling has been done to make the dropdown more visable but as you can see in this picture below that it is hidden behind another ship select box (ship2 in the Hierarchy).

[image]

I have tried making the Z coordinate larger/small and even if I have it come closer to the camera it still is represented behind the ship2 gameobject.  I am at a total loss for ideas on how to approach this and if anyone could shed some light on this that would be awesome!

Here are 2 more screen shots just in-case the first 2 images were not enough information to go on.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, your UI is behind the ship but you want it to be above the ship. If that's the case read below, else leave a comment.

objects in the hierarchy is **rendered** based on the **order** of your **objects** in the **hierarchy**, not the depth. *The Unity UI is rendered from top to button in the hierarchy*. Don**'**t go changing the z-axis if you want to change the display order. It doesn't work like **NGUI**.

If you want any object to be displayed on top, it has to be put bellow the object in the hierarchy NOT on top.

If **object A** is on **top** of **object B** in the scene, the problem is from the hierarchy. Go to the hierarchy and put **object B** below **object A** if you want **object B** to be on **top** of **object A**.

Also, **don't scale** the UI the way you did in picture #2. Change the scale of **shipRow1** back to **1,1,1** then use the **Width** and the **Height** properties to change its size.

Comment: You are correct when you mentioned the hierarchy for the answer to my problem.  Thank you very much!!

Comment: If possible can you explain why what I did with the shipRow1 is bad please.  It seemed like the better way to do it rather than changing multiple child objects.

Comment: When you scale it like that, you lose the graphic quality on bigger screen. I may look good now but when scaling up, it will give you low quality image. I did it your way on my text in the beginning but then realized that the quality is awful. You may have to start it all over again but it is worth it. Other gameobjects in your scene seem to be ok except the shipRow1  object. Any object that has >1,1,1 as the scale is not good but that is up to you. you can do it your way and lose the great quality of your ui.

Comment: Ahh right on!  That is some really good information to know!  Now it makes sense on some scenes I have built and looked at in my web browser that look HORRIBLE!  Thank you once again Programmer.

Comment: no problem. the same thing happened to me on my HQ texture.